# Facebook Real-Time updates: comment on post vs comment on album

Tags: facebook

Status entry comment:

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"106182246249179","time":1386582683,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"comment","verb":"add","comment_id":"185457974988272_294727","parent_id":185457974988272,"sender_id":106182246249179,"created_time":1386582683}}]}]}
```

Album comment:

```
{"object":"page","entry":[{"id":"106182246249179","time":1386581446,"changes":[{"field":"feed","value":{"item":"comment","verb":"add","comment_id":"185444231656313_190183","parent_id":185444231656313,"sender_id":100006218707108,"created_time":1386581446}}]}]}
```

They seem impossible to distinguish. However, the first one's real post id is pageid_parentid = 106182246249179_185457974988272. If you try to do the same thing with the album comment to get the feed from the stream FQL table, you won't get anything (or an exception with graph api).

Has anyone found a way to distinguish somehow between the two?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
First you need the `object_id`

```
object_id=pageid_parentid
```

Make this api call with the object id:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/{object-id}?fields=type,status_type&access_token=token
```

The response should look something like this if the parent is a post:

```
{
  "type": "status",
  "id": "106182246249179_185457974988272"
}
```

If it's an album, it will look like this:

```
{
  "type": "photo",
  "id": "106182246249179_185457974988272"
}
```